# Git Access Issues After Update on CentOS to OpenSSh 5.3

Tags: git, ssh, centos, gitlab, openssh

I have GitLab installed on a CentOS server. I just did a 'yum update', which included updates to openssh, openssh-askpass, openssh-client and openssh-server to version 5.3p1. Now none of my users can access their code via git. I tried a debug session "ssh -vT git@[my server]" and the following output appears:

```
$ ssh -vT git@[myserver]
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to 172.16.2.156 [172.16.2.156] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /c/Users/anne.racel/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/anne.racel/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /c/Users/anne.racel/.ssh/id_dsa type 2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_4.6
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-cbc hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host '172.16.2.156' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /c/Users/anne.racel/.ssh/known_hosts:8
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /c/Users/anne.racel/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/anne.racel/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/anne.racel/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
git@172.16.2.156's password:
```

The /var/log/secure file showed the following the first few times:

```
Oct 30 15:54:55 SRV-GITLAB-001 sshd[13526]: Invalid user Anne.Racel from 192.168.253.77
Oct 30 15:54:55 SRV-GITLAB-001 sshd[13528]: input_userauth_request: invalid user Anne.Racel
```

But then I started getting no output whatsoever.

I've tried modifying the sshd_config file to include following (note: the timestamp on the file shows that it wasn't changed during the update), as per instructions I found online:

```
### changing this, hoping to solve our RSA keys problem ###
RSAAuthentication yes
PubkeyAuthentication yes
AuthorizedKeysFile      /var/opt/gitlab/.ssh/authorized_keys
#AuthorizedKeysCommand none
#AuthorizedKeysCommandRunAs nobody
```

I've tried deleting my old keys in Gitlab and adding new ones (RSA and DSA). I confirmed that the keys did appear in the /gitlab/.ssh/known_hosts file. I've tried resetting pam_tally2, just in case. I checked the permissions on the .ssh directory and containing files. Nothing seems to make a difference.

I can ssh into the server, so passwords are working. It just seems to be something about using a key to connect that isn't working.

Comment: Do you get anything more from ssh if you use `-vvv`? Those error lines look like it was complaining about a username not a key.

Comment: Here's the response when I try upping the verbosity (the relevant portion): 'debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/anne.racel/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mi
c,password
debug1: Offering public key: /c/Users/anne.racel/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply'

Answer (score 2):

OK - I finally found the solution.

The upgrade seems to have increased the SELinux security level to 'enforcing'. Since our server is behind a firewall, I've decreased it to 'permissive' and everything appears to be working again.

Thanks to the answer here: https://serverfault.com/questions/321534/public-key-authentication-fails-only%20when-sshd-is-daemon